# how to delete selected Text Widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Here I want added multiple Text Widget in Stack Widget. But I want to delete any particular selected widget. so how can I accomplish this in flutter? I added this Multiple Text Widget in Stack Widget.

Comment: Isnt `Chip` helpful? Anyway You can do it easily by using `GestureDetector`(there are many widgets, you can use)

Comment: I already used `GestureDetector`, but I want to delete only selected widget.

Comment: give me suggestion for other widget for this functionality...@Blasanka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working !
Modify it as per your requirement.

```
class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  List<Model> list = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(actions: [
        IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle), onPressed: addWidget)
      ]),
      body: Stack(
        children: list.map((m) => m.w).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }

  addWidget() {
    Model m = new Model();
    m.id = DateTime.now();
    m.w = InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          deleteWidget(m.id);
        },
        child: Text('New Text : ' + DateTime.now().toString()));
    setState((){
      list.add(m);
    });
  }

  deleteWidget(DateTime id) {
    setState(() {
      print('reached');
      list.removeWhere((m) => m.id == id);
    });
  }
}

class Model {
  Widget w;
  DateTime id;
  Model();
}
```

Comment: This snippet is working, but now problem is how can I set `image` as background in `Stack Widget`@Naveen Avidi

Comment: also I want make this `Text Widget` `Draggable`. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Try wrapping text with positioned draggable then update left, top of positioned widget on dragend

Comment: I already tried with positioned draggable widget, but it is  not working. Any other solution, then help me to solve this problem.@Naveen Avidi

Comment: Also I want to save this edited image and share this edited image, Can you help me to solve this problem?..@Naveen Avidi